# Insert base64 string to blog mysql with node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, base64, blob

I want to insert a base64 string into a mysql blog. To do it, I use the code below but when I run the code I have the following error:

> ER_DATA_TOO_LONG: Data too long for column 'Immagine' at row 1

Immagine is base64 image(png or jpg)

Node.js Code:

```
async function inserimentoTipologia(Nome, Immagine) {
    var ret = true;
    var imgCast = new Buffer.from(Immagine, "base64");
    checkValueLoad = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return db.con.query("Insert into Categoria(Nome,Immagine) values( ? , ? ); ", [Nome, imgCast], function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                ManageError.SendError("Errore: nella funzione inserimentoTipologia " + err);
                ret = false;
            }
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Your not inserting a `base64` string - `imgCast` is a `Buffer`. Of what type is `Imagine`?

Comment: Agree with @eol. . What type you set for `Immagine` column? And second try like this : `const imgCast = new Buffer.from(Immagine).toString('base64')`.

Comment: immagine is base64 png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var ret = true;
    checkValueLoad = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return db.con.query("Insert into Categoria(Nome,Immagine) values( ? , ? ); ", [Nome, Buffer.from(Immagine).toString('base64')], function(err, results) {
            if (err) {
                ManageError.SendError("Errore: nella funzione inserimentoTipologia " + err);
                ret = false;
            }
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
    return ret;
}
```